# remote-exec in NodeJS not working with passphrase

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am trying to execute commands in remote system terminal using code below

```
    var restify = require('restify');
    var rexec = require('remote-exec');

    function respond(req, res, next) {
        var connection_options = {
            username: 'root',
            passphrase: 'xxxxx'
        };

        var hosts = [
            'n.n.n.n'];

        var cmds = [
            'ls -l',
            'cat /etc/hosts'];
        console.log('Recieved Request');
        rexec(hosts, cmds, connection_options, function (err) {
            console.log(34455);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Great Success!!');
            }
            res.send('Wait..');
        });
        // res.send('hello ' + req.params.name);
    }

    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.get('/hello/:name', respond);
    server.head('/hello/:name', respond);

    server.listen(8080, function () {
        console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
    });
```

But this is not working, Am I missing something? And one more thing is the node server running and the remote IP I am trying to connect both are same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the connection options. `passphrase` is for when you're authenticating using encrypted private keys. For authenticating with the user's password use `password` instead.